# Can we disable line-wrapping on the 'badges' on the bottom of our profile?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the bottom of [my user page](http://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) it shows the badges I have gotten. However, many of them have linebreaks and this makes them look bad. Like "Nice\nQuestion x\n4" (with \n showing where I currently see linebreaks). These should be given a CSS style="white-space: nowrap" or something.

Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9822/can-we-disable-line-wrapping-on-the-%27badges%27-on-the-bottom-of-our-profile?/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-04-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-04-26**:
Actually, the 'tags' category as well, but it's not nearly as bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please report this upstream at [askbot.org](http://askbot.org)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2011-04-27**:
Done and done! "Thanks, fixed in 0.6.80 (well at least made look a bit better)."